# Hibernate Option In Power Menu

Tags: release-hera, settings

Is there any way to add "Hibernate" to the power menu in Hera as in Freya?
"sudo systemctl hibernate" works perfectly.

Comment: I haven't tested it, I'm nowhere near that PC right now, so I'll just link it [here](https://www.fosslinux.com/187/how-to-add-hibernate-to-the-power-wingpanel-in-elementary-os.htm). That may still work, though it's a bit old. A glance over it and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, unless eOS changed that since then.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Well,no. The "sudo systemctl hibernate" doesn't work.Just found it out now

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip.
However to get ACPI part working, I needed to add *%e* in event file, like: action=/etc/acpi/hibernate.sh %e Would probably be interesting to trigger hibernate on battery low power

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate button [was recently removed](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/pull/112) because it had stopped working
due to some changes in Ubuntu (upon which Elementary is based). Like many others,
suspend doesn't work very well on my PC, so it's very important to me that hibernate
work properly.

## Fix Resume-From-Disk

At least in my experience, if you try to run `systemctl hibernate` after a fresh
install of Hera, the system will happily suspend itself to disk. But it will not
actually *resume* after pressing the power button; instead, it performs a fresh
boot as if you had simply cut the power instead of hibernating.

The issue is that the kernel does not know how to find the swapfile during early
boot, so it is unable to detect that the system was previously suspended. To fix
this, we need to provide details about the system's swapfile using the `resume`
and `resume_offset` kernel parameters.

> These instructions were taken from [the Arch Wiki page on hibernation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file).

First, determine the partition UUID and disk offset of your swapfile:

```
$ findmnt -no UUID -T /swapfile
<uuid>
$ sudo filefrag -v /swapfile | awk '{ if($1=="0:"){print $4} }'
<offset>..
```

Then, open */etc/default/grub* in a text editor and add the `resume` and `resume_offset`
kernel parameters to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` as follows, replacing
*<uuid>* and *<offset>* with the values from the previous step.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... resume=UUID=<uuid> resume_offset=<offset>"
```

Finally, you must run `sudo update-grub` in order for changes to */etc/default/grub*
to take effect.

## ACPI Events

When on battery power, I like for my laptop to hibernate when the lid is shut. I
also like for the power button to trigger hibernation regardless of whether on AC
or battery power. This is easy enough to achieve by creating a custom ACPI event
handler.

Before you set this up, be sure to disable any power button or lid close events
in the System Settings app, as these could interfere with the new event handler
and cause unwanted behavior.

First, create the file */etc/acpi/events/hibernate* with the following contents:

```
event=.*
action=/etc/acpi/hibernate.sh
```

Then, create the file */etc/acpi/hibernate.sh*. This script will be executed any
time an ACPI event occurs. Add the following lines to trigger hibernation as outlined
above, or feel free to do something different if you wish!

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in

        # Hibernate when power button is pressed
        button/power)
                /bin/systemctl hibernate
                ;;

        # Hibernate when lid is shut while on battery
        button/lid)
                if [ $3 = close ]
                then
                        AC=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC0/online)
                        if [ $AC = 0 ] # AC adapter not connected
                        then
                                /bin/systemctl hibernate
                        fi
                fi
                ;;

        # Hibernate when AC adapter is unplugged while lid is shut
        ac_adapter)
                if [ $4 = 00000000 ] # unplugged
                then
                        LID=$(cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state | awk '{print $2}')
                        if [ $LID = closed ]
                        then
                                /bin/systemctl hibernate
                        fi
                fi
                ;;
esac
```

Finally, mark the new script as executable, then send a signal to *acpid* to load
the new event handler:

```
# chmod +x /etc/acpi/power.sh
# systemctl kill -s HUP acpid
```

## Expand Swap File

Hibernation works by storing the state of all open programs to the swapfile, which
can fail if the file is not large enough.

Hera appears to create a 2GB swapfile by default, which may not be large enough
to support hibernation if you do a lot of multitasking. A good rule of thumb is
for your swapfile to be at least as large as RAM.

Here's how to expand your swapfile to 8GB. For different sizes, just tweak the `dd`
command options.

```
# swapoff /swapfile
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile blocksize=1M count=8192
# mkswap /swapfile
# swapon -a
```

Note resizing the swapfile may change its disk offset, requiring you to use a different
value for the `resume_offset` kernel parameter.

## Official Support

Searching GitHub is a great way to understand the status of certain features from
the developers' perspective. Here's a query that shows all the activity related
to the keyword "hibernate":

https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aelementary+hibernate&type=issues

Looks like there are some open PRs to get the hibernate button working again in
the UI. For the latest updates, I'd recommend subscribing to notifications
for this PR:

https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-session/pull/102